# Стилистически верно ли употреблено "со свежим взглядом"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

> От картинок собраний разных академий уже кружилась голова. Я сделала
>   перерыв – посвятила неделю ранним римским мозаикам и **со свежим
>   взглядом** отправилась в палаццо Барберни.

Какой предлог возможен (и возможен ли) со "свежим взглядом"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, не очень хорошо. Я бы сказал так:

> Я сделала перерыв – посвятила неделю ранним римским мозаикам и отправилась в палаццо Барберни, чтобы свежим взглядом посмотреть на (...) [и оценить (...)].